# Replacing newlines with commas at every third occurrence using AWK?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

For example: a given file has the following lines:

```
1
alpha
beta
2
charlie
delta
10
text
test
```

I'm trying to get the following output using `awk`:

```
1,alpha,beta  
2,charlie,delta  
10,text,test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk can handle this easily by manipulating `ORS`:

```
awk '{ORS=","} !(NR%3){ORS="\n"} 1' file

1,alpha,beta
2,charlie,delta
10,text,test
```

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple. Use the **output record separator** as follows. Specify the comma delimiter when the line number is not divisible by 3 and the newline otherwise:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%3?",":"\n"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a tool for this kind of text processing `pr`

```
$ pr -3ats, file

1,alpha,beta
2,charlie,delta
10,text,test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `xargs` with sed to coalesce multiple lines into single lines, useful to know:

`cat file|xargs -n3|sed 's/ /,/g'`